# Jasper reports, getting error message/empty report while compiling jrxml file even after datasource test is passed

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am using JasperStudio and Jasper server 6.2 windows version. In the local environment firstly I have tested data source, postgreSQL JDBC connection, connection which is successfull and I have created a domain and linked the datasource. I took the working jrxml file which needs an input string. I have created the report in view>repository>create>jasperReport and while configuring the report I have given the jrxml file which is working in production server and set an input field as mandatory. till now everything is fine but when I click on the report it is asking for input value, when an input value is given and clickon apply, it is showing the following error message:

```
Error Message
Error filling report
Error Trace

com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSException: Error filling report Arguments: at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$FillResultListener.reportFillError(EngineServiceImpl.java:1294) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle.notifyError(BaseFillHandle.java:210) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFill.run(BaseFillHandle.java:134) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$SynchronousExecutor.execute(EngineServiceImpl.java:922) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle.startFill(BaseFillHandle.java:164) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$AsynchronousReportFiller.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:878) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1774) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportFill.runWithDataSource(EngineServiceImpl.java:1118) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportFill.runReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1047) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportRunnable.run(EngineServiceImpl.java:944) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.DiagnosticLoggingContextCompatibleExecutorService$1.run(DiagnosticLoggingContextCompatibleExecutorService.java:61) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.lang.RuntimeException: exception initting subfilters at com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.strategy.StrategyAwareDomainQueryExecuter.createDatasource(StrategyAwareDomainQueryExecuter.java:165) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1129) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:696) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.setParameters(BaseReportFiller.java:437) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:526) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFill.run(BaseFillHandle.java:119) ... 11 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: exception initting subfilters at com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.strategy.DomainDataStrategy.getInitialSubFilterList(DomainDataStrategy.java:629) at com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.strategy.BaseDataStrategy.initSubFilterList(BaseDataStrategy.java:424) at com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.strategy.DomainDataStrategy.getBaseQueryDataSet(DomainDataStrategy.java:145) at com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.strategy.DomainQueryDataStrategy.getBaseQueryDataSet(DomainQueryDataStrategy.java:38) at com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.strategy.CommonDomainDataStrategy.createQuery(CommonDomainDataStrategy.java:736) at com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.strategy.CommonDomainDataStrategy.getQuery(CommonDomainDataStrategy.java:681) at com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.strategy.CommonDomainDataStrategy.getWorkingDataSet(CommonDomainDataStrategy.java:1232) at com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.strategy.CommonDomainDataStrategy.getWorkingDataSet(CommonDomainDataStrategy.java:1220) at com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.strategy.StrategyAwareDomainQueryExecuter.createDatasource(StrategyAwareDomainQueryExecuter.java:156) ... 16 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.jaspersoft.commons.dataset.expr.DataSetExpressionParser.varRef(DataSetExpressionParser.java:1703) at com.jaspersoft.commons.dataset.expr.DataSetExpressionParser.term(DataSetExpressionParser.java:1349) at com.jaspersoft.commons.dataset.expr.DataSetExpressionParser.multDivExpr(DataSetExpressionParser.java:1003) at com.jaspersoft.commons.dataset.expr.DataSetExpressionParser.addSubExpr(DataSetExpressionParser.java:888) at com.jaspersoft.commons.dataset.expr.DataSetExpressionParser.comparisonExpr(DataSetExpressionParser.java:601) at com.jaspersoft.commons.dataset.expr.DataSetExpressionParser.notExpr(DataSetExpressionParser.java:499) at com.jaspersoft.commons.dataset.expr.DataSetExpressionParser.andExpr(DataSetExpressionParser.java:423) at com.jaspersoft.commons.dataset.expr.DataSetExpressionParser.orExpr(DataSetExpressionParser.java:353) at com.jaspersoft.commons.dataset.expr.DataSetExpressionParser.booleanExpr(DataSetExpressionParser.java:298) at
```

when I try to compile the same jrxml in JasperStudio then it is giving me an empty report with design but no data when empty data adapter is selected and it  is giving complete empty document when a datasource is selected.

Comment: Some jrxml? some more log [mcve]

Comment: I have added some more log

Comment: You have a problem in one of your printWhenExpression... a nullpointer... show jrxml or find it youself. Its something like $V{var}.equals.... or calling other method, on a $V{var} that is null.... if you can't find it post complete jrxml, please ping me by doing @Petter if you find it or if you need help..

Comment: The same file working for my colleague. @petter

Comment: maybe different data... (different param, different datasource) but I'm true I'm guessing some since I can't see jrxml

Comment: can i have your email id, i will send jrxml file. I cannot post here in public @PetterFriberg

Comment: I'm sorry prefer to keep it private... cut out all printWhenExpression and we can check thoose.. (now I have little time... need to run, but I will tomorrow morning)